# Transparency and .PNG : saved image is different to rendered image

Tags: rendering

There is a problem I don't know what causes it. When I render I got a photo with every specular light. But when I save that render as png and with a transparent option on it it just doesn't save it correctly.

If I save it as a jpg it saves it correctly but the picture won't be transparent anymore.

Here top one is rendered picture. The bottom one is saved (I got both of them with the Snipping tool)

Rendered image:
[image: rendered image]

Saved image:
[image: saved image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. What do you mean "Just doesn't save correctly"? Is it not transparent in PNG? Did you select RGBA when saving as PNG?. JPG does not support Alpha / Transparent. What method are you using to save your image?

Comment: @Emir i used rgba transparent png and as you can see rendered and saved pictures are different i dont know why and what do you mean by which method im using to save image ?

Comment: Blending your images in Layers with Difference mode make images the same, the only difference is stronger outer white edge  of rendered than saved (but it is quite hard to compare from your screens exactly. It seems to me as alias/antialisa or premultiply alpha issue. What version of Blender you used? What viewer (app) you have used to view saved image?

Comment: See other answer. PNG is a wretchedly broken format and should be abandoned as it *does not work to communicate alpha*. No, really. It’s a broken design.

Comment: @vklidu i think it premultiply alpha issue because when i use alpha convert in compositing tab it shows exactly what i get , blender version 3.4 and viewer windows default pictures and photoshop

Comment: @vklidu believe it or not i changed my monitor settings + ior and frensel settings + reduced compression 9 and i got a bit of result but again not same picture but close enough

Comment: Render is viewed in Blender still in Linear ColourSpace, but saved image is at first - data croped to fits 8 bit PNG, secondly - you use another app to see these data so there can be a shifted data inside this viewer. If you want to check if it is PNG issue save render as full OpenEXR file and check it in Photoshop. Or at least open saved image back in Blender to see if there is a difference.